# Can I, as a Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber, run a DevOps Server 2019 on premise (Production) without buying additional licences?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

On [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/) page the wording is "Visual Studio subscriptions include one server license plus a user CAL for the subscriber". I simply cannot find additional information that explains this in more detail.

I understand that I need OS and DB licenses, I'm referring to DevOps Server specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Additional information here: [Visual Studio Licensing Whitepaper May 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Visual-Studio-Licensing-Whitepaper-May-2019.pdf). In **Visual Studio Azure DevOps Server 2019** Licensing section:

> **You must acquire an operating system license for each machine running**
>   **Azure DevOps Server 2019, any of the additional software, or the SQL**
>   **Server database for Azure DevOps Server.** You must acquire an operating
>   system license even when your use of Azure DevOps Server is licensed
>   as part of a Visual Studio subscription. For Windows Server-based
>   deployments where Windows Server is licensed on a Server/CAL basis,
>   each user or device that accesses Azure DevOps Server data (on a read
>   or write basis) must also have a Windows Server CAL.
>
> **One instance of the Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Standard software can be**
>   **used as the Azure DevOps Server 2019 database, except for Azure DevOps**
>   **Server 2019 Express which uses SQL Server 2017 Express**. Azure DevOps
>   Server 2019 uses Microsoft SQL Server as its data repository and
>   provides the right to deploy one instance of SQL Server 2019 Standard
>   software per Azure DevOps Server 2019 server license. This is not a
>   separate SQL Server license. This instance of SQL Server can run on a
>   separate server but can only be used by Azure DevOps Server—not for
>   any other purposes. If you do use the SQL Server software for purposes
>   other than Azure DevOps Server, then you must license that use
>   separately.
>
> **SQL Server Enterprise can be used for Azure DevOps Server 2019, but**
>   **must be licensed separately.** If you wish to use a different edition of
>   SQL Server (such as Enterprise) as the Azure DevOps Server 2019
>   database, then you must acquire that license separately.

Answer (score 1):

The part that Explains it is:

> **Visual Studio subscriptions.** Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription,
>   Visual Studio Professional Subscription, Visual Studio Test
>   Professional Subscription, MSDN Platforms, and all Visual Studio cloud
>   subscribers can download and deploy one instance of Azure DevOps
>   Server 2019. These same Visual Studio subscribers are granted a Azure
>   DevOps Server 2019 User CAL to be used within their organization (it
>   is not valid for use of Azure DevOps Server acquired by a different
>   organization).